# PHPExcel - horizontal split worksheet

Tags: php, split, phpexcel

I have to create an Excelsheet with PHPExcel, which has an horizont Splitscreen.

For Example: Column A to C are fixed and the others are able to scroll.

Loading an existing Excelfile, which already has an Sheetsplit don´t work. The import is loosing the formation and load an single sheet.

Answer (score 2):

To set a "split screen" at column `D`, you'd use:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('D1');
```

which will fix columns A-C, and columns `D` onward will be scrollable

---

But what format is the file that you're reading which already has a split screen? PHPExcel should read this correctly from valid OfficeOpenXML (`.xlsx`) or BIFF-format (`.xls`) files, unless syou have `readDataOnly` set to `true`